# Отобразить значение 3-х переменных по очереди с помощью метода alert

Tags: javascript, alert

Всем привет, коллеги!
Несколько часов бьюсь над задачкой и никак не получается решить. Буду очень рада помощи. Условие такое вот:

1. Создать 3 переменные с использованием ключевого слова var с идентификаторами a, b, c.
2. Переменной с идентификатором a присвоить значение false. Переменной с идентификатором b присвоить значение null. Переменная с идентификатором c должна принимать значение undefined.
3. Отобразить значение 3-х переменных по очереди в модальные окна (то есть с помощью метода alert).

Решала по-всячески, но все никак не получается. Самым логичным кажется такое решение

```
var a = false
var b = null
var c = undefined
alert(a)
alert(b)
alert(c)
```

Но нет - не работает :(((

Comment: Что именно "не работает"? Всё выводится как и надо

Comment: Да вот решаю задачки на этом сайте https://itvdn.com/ru/skills/practicums/javascript-for-beginners/lesson/javascript-introduction и выдает ошибку при отправки ответа. Вы допустили ошибку. Перейдите к следующему заданию или попробуйте еще раз :((

Comment: Вы должны описать детально всё в вопросе... все эти "не работает" и "допустили ошибку" ни о чём никому не говорит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На сайтах с автоматической проверкой часто приходится бороться с валидатором, даже если решение выглядит правильным и выполняет то, что требуется. В данном случае добавьте `;` в конце каждой строки:

```
var a = false;
var b = null;
var c = undefined;
alert(a);
alert(b);
alert(c);
```

Comment: Алекс, огромное вам спасибо! И главное мне это приходило в голову, но я почему-то добавляла ; везде, кроме последней строки. Да, тут именно шла речь о таком тренажере с автоматической проверкой. Еще раз спасибо!